# Submit button issue

Tags: javascript, loops, submit-button

how can i have a submit button which actually is in form and submits the data, here problem is if i move the submit button inside the loop it comes up with every input field requested, how can i stop that and have only one submit button at end off the input fields.

```js
const div = document.querySelector(".addHere");

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", addInputs);

function addInputs() {

const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);

  if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
    alert("Wrong input");
  } else {
    for (let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i++) {
      const form = document.createElement("form");
      form.method = "post";
      form.action = "#";

      const input1 = document.createElement("input");
      input1.type = "text";
      input1.maxLength = "12";
      input1.className = "factor";
      input1.required = true;

      const input2 = document.createElement("input");
      input2.type = "text";
      input2.maxLength = "1";
      input2.className = "priority";
      input2.required = true;

      const br = document.createElement("br");

      form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
      form.appendChild(input1);
      form.appendChild(input2);
      form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

      div.appendChild(form);
    }

    const sub = document.createElement("button");
    sub.type = "submit";
    sub.value = "Submit";
    sub.className = "subButton";
    sub.textContent = "Submit";

    div.appendChild(sub);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="addHere"></div>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputValue" placeholder="insert numbers:" />
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and fixed your typo

Comment: I suggest do not generate the form like that. There was also a typo , and yes, put input value into that function

Comment: @ptts so how should i generate a form dynamically?

Comment: Do you have to generate it dynamically? I would simply have it coded as HTML, even google themselves use HTML for their very beautiful Materialize UI. Plus the user input, I assume this does not go to a database or anything, but learn a server side language asap to validate user input, just jump into it, php and nodejs with express are productive without much celebration around them:-)

Comment: @ptts yes i want to generate it dynamically using js as i want to have user decide how much input it wants, i am going to learn nodejs once i get my hands good on vanilla js itself, well do you have some tips to improve?

Comment: @prph8 I fixed your script instead of completely rewriting it in some functional format.

Answer (score 1):

- Place your Submit button in HTML
- Use CSS `:empty` to determine if an element has no descendants. Hide button submit if empty using `#forms:empty ~ #submit { display: none; }`

```js
// UTILITY FUNCTIONS:
const ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});
const ELS   = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const EL    = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);

// APP:
const EL_forms = EL("#forms");
const EL_value = EL("#value");
const EL_add   = EL("#add"); // be more specific, add IDs to your elements

EL_add.addEventListener("click", addInputs);

const customForm = () => {
  const form = ELNew("form",  {method:"post", action:"#"});
  const inpA = ELNew("input", {type:"text", maxLength:"12", className:"factor", required:true});
  const inpB = ELNew("input", {type:"number", maxLength:"1", className:"priority", required:true});
  form.append(inpA, inpB);
  return form;
}

function addInputs() {
  const times = parseInt(EL_value.value, 10);
  if (isNaN(times)) return alert("Wrong input");
  const DF_forms = [...Array(times)].reduce((DF) => (DF.append(customForm()), DF), new DocumentFragment);
  EL_forms.append(DF_forms);
  EL_value.value = ""; // Reset input value
}
```

```css
#forms:empty ~ #submit { display: none; }
#forms form {padding-bottom: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="forms"></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="value" placeholder="Insert number:" />
<button id="add" class="btn">+</button><br>
<button id="send" type="button" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

If you want to use JS to toggle your button visibility:

```
/* UTILITY */
.u-none {display:none !important;}
```

```js
EL("#send").classList.toggle("u-none", !EL("form", EL_forms));
```

Comment: sir am new to programming, and impressed at the way you wrote code, i want some tips on how to write javascript like this and is your code written in functional programming paradigm?

Comment: I would recommend to never use the reserved word `submit` for any name or ID. If the element with name or ID submit is in a form, the form immediately loses it's ability to be submitted by script.

Comment: This code looks like reinventing jQuery... Not sure I see the point. Especially not if OP does not grok your code.

Comment: **Thank you** for pointing out the *submit* quirk @mplungjan

Answer (score -1):

- spell fuction correctly
- move the const inputValue to INSIDE the function
- move the form OUTSIDE the loop
- Only create the submit if it does not exist.

```js
const div = document.querySelector(".addHere");

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", addInputs);

function addInputs() {
  const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
  if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
    alert("Wrong input");
    return;
  }
  const form = document.createElement("form");
  form.method = "post";
  form.action = "#";
  for (let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i++) {
    const input1 = document.createElement("input");
    input1.type = "text";
    input1.maxLength = "12";
    input1.className = "factor";
    input1.required = true;

    const input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.type = "text";
    input2.maxLength = "1";
    input2.className = "priority";
    input2.required = true;

    const br = document.createElement("br");

    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    form.appendChild(input1);
    form.appendChild(input2);
    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

    div.appendChild(form);
  }

  let sub = document.getElementById("sub") || document.createElement("button");
  if (!sub.id) { // it is a new button
    sub.id = "sub";
    sub.type = "submit";
    sub.value = "Submit";
    sub.className = "subButton";
    sub.textContent = "Submit";
  }
  form.appendChild(sub); // moves if exists

}
```

```html
<div class="addHere"></div>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputValue" placeholder="insert numbers:" />
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, would you like to elaborate on the sub button you created, how and when it will work and why if loop surrounds it attributes, thanks.

Comment: I assign and existing button to a variable. If the button does not exist, the OR (||) assigns a new button. If sub has an ID it already existed - if not, it’s a new button so I add it to the DOM